# Why would you go that far for me

Tags: meaning-in-context

The context is about a girl who's been helping another girl (still helping her) and gave her her position at work . so she asks the first : you've been helping me I don't deserve this etc " why would you go that far for me ? "

What does it mean ? Why do you help me or why did you help me or something else ?

Comment: Is this from *Attack on Titan*?

Answer (score 1):

The key phrase here is **go far**.

[Collins Dictionary's first American English definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/go-far) for "go far" I think gets at the notion used here:

> to cover much extent; last long

So given that definition, the meaning of the larger phrase is not so much "why did you help me [in general]" as it is "why did you help me *that much*."

To do a favor or two for someone is one thing; to give up your job for them is a much bigger deal. And especially if the girl doesn't think she deserves the help, she probably thinks that the other girl giving up her job is more help than she could reasonably ask for.

The girl getting the help is asking the other girl why she would do so much to help her.

Comment: In other words since the girl is stil help it's like saying " what's your reasons to help so much like that"

Comment: @Meaning Correct!